# Why is my function running in a infinite loop

Tags: javascript, function

```
  for( let i = 0; i = 3; i++){
```

Could you explain to me why this function runs infintely.

This is the whole code

```
function sayThanks(){
    console.log("Thank you for your purchase! We appreciate your business.");
  }
  
  for( let i = 0; = i 3; i++){
  sayThanks();
  }
```

Comment: What do you think `i = 3` does and evaluates to?

Comment: Your loop condition is an assignment. Perhaps review [for loops](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for).

Comment: Because `i = 3` evaluates to `3` which is a truthy, which leads to the continuation of thel loop

Comment: Check out for loop: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second part of the for loop (the condition part) is written wrong here because you have to set a condition that stops the loop when this condition is met, but `i = 3;` means that i is always equal to 3 which makes the loop run infinitely